# Raspberry pi zero video playback running too fast

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, gpio

Pls help. It is sooo urgent. I am experiencing issues with video playback running too fast on your Raspberry Pi Zero. I use VNC video player. And when i save bvideo it displays so fast.

Comment: Delete this question and edit your first question and include the fact you are using VNC to play back your videos.